# What do i need to do to make ruby-debug19 run on ubuntu 10.04 with the ruby-full package from the repository?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-debug

i just installed the latest ubuntu version and the ruby-full package from the repository. Additionally i installed rubygems (1.3.7) and tried to do gem1.9.1 install ruby-debug1.9 as mentioned on http://wiki.github.com/mark-moseley/ruby-debug/installation-command-line-version
but whatever i do i can't install the gem. Installation terminates with:

---

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug19:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
 --without-opt-dir
 --with-opt-include
 --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 --with-opt-lib
 --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 --with-make-prog
 --without-make-prog
 --srcdir=.
 --curdir
 --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
extconf.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- ruby_core_source (LoadError)
 from extconf.rb:2:in`'

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache19-0.5.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache19-0.5.11/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out

---

But installing the ruby_core_source gem hasn't change anything. What is nessecary to install the gem?

Answer (score 0):

Install ruby-debug19 first:

```
sudo gem install ruby-debug19
```